# Fritz!Box & Ubuntu: Expose URL in LAN with Apache Httpd and Bind

Tags: apache-2.4, bind, local-area-network, url, ubuntu-20.04

I hope someone can help me with this - I thought - simple task.

**Situation:**

On my private LAN I run an Internet-Router ("Fritz!Box") and a Raspberry Pi with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS on it. I developed a little Spring Boot Web-App for private purposes that I only want to use in my LAN (or maybe reach via VPN from the outside). The native URL of the Web-App is "http://ubuntu:8080", because my Raspberry is called "ubuntu" and the app runs on a Tomcat-Server.
Now I want to expose an URL like e.g. "http://thats-my.app" inside the LAN and use it as base URL for the app. For the moment, curl on the ubuntu can reach it, my other PC can't.

Even better would be a FQDN "http://wow.thats-my.app" (with a subdomain) so I can use the same domain and top-level-domain for all apps, and only vary the subdomain, like "http://super.thats-my.app" and so on..
Disclaimer: Since I work via SSH all configuration is done Terminal-only. Please consider that I don't use the Desktop Surface of Ubuntu.

Thank you in advance for your time and hopefully for your help!

**Here are the setups I did to the ubuntu system. What is not shown here is commented out!:**

*ufw*

```
Status: active

     To                         Action      From
     --                         ------      ----
[ 1] 9090/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # UBUNTU-COCKPIT
[ 2] 3306/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # MYSQL
[ 3] Apache Full                ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # :80,:443
[ 4] Bind9                      ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # :53
[ 5] OpenSSH                    ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # :22
[ 6] 8080:8090/tcp              ALLOW IN    Anywhere                   # TOMCAT
[ 7] 9090/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # UBUNTU-COCKPIT
[ 8] 3306/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # MYSQL
[ 9] Apache Full (v6)           ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # :80,:443
[10] Bind9 (v6)                 ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # :53
[11] OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # :22
[12] 8080:8090/tcp (v6)         ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)              # TOMCAT
```

*/etc/hosts*

```
127.0.0.1 localhost.localdomain localhost
127.0.1.1 ubuntu
127.0.1.1 thats-my.app
```

(--> no entries for IPv6)

*/etc/apache2/sites-available/thats-my.conf*

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName thats-my.app
        ServerAlias thats-my
        ProxyRequests Off
        <Proxy *>
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
        </Proxy>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass               / http://localhost:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse        / http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

--> Symbolic link to sites-enabled directory

*/etc/bind/named.conf.local*

```
zone "thats-my.app" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/forward.thats-my.app.db";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "178.168.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/reverse.thats-my.app.db";
        allow-update { none; };
};
```

*/etc/bind/named.conf.options*

```
options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";
        forwarders {
        1.1.1.1;
        1.0.0.1;
        8.8.8.8;
        8.8.4.4;
        };
        dnssec-validation auto;
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
        allow-query { any; };
};
```

*/etc/bind/forward.thats-my.app.db*

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.thats-my.app. admin.ns1.thats-my.app. (
                              5         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.thats-my.app.
ns1     IN      A       192.168.178.23
```

*/etc/bind/reverse.thats-my.app.db*

```
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     thats-my.app. admin.thats-my.app. (
                              4         ; Serial
                         604800         ; Refresh
                          86400         ; Retry
                        2419200         ; Expire
                         604800 )       ; Negative Cache TTL
;
@       IN      NS      ns1.thats-my.app.
ns1     IN      A       192.168.178.23
23      IN      PTR     ns1.thats-my.app.
```

*--> input to Terminal:*

```
sudo systemctl restart named
sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo systemctl restart bind9
```

*--> DNS Configuration in the Router*

Set DNS IPv4 IP to 192.168.178.23 (primary and secondary)

Set DNS IPv6 IP to IPv6 address of the ubuntu machine (primary and secondary)

**Here's what I got:**

*On the local Ubuntu-Server*

```
$ curl thats-my.app -> OK
$ dig thats-my.app -> status: NOERROR   *but*  SERVER 1.1.1.1#53 ???
$ dig thats-my.app @127.0.1.1 -> "connection timed out!"
$ dig thats-my.app @192.198.178.23 -> "connections timed out!"
```

*On the LAN Windows-PC PowerShell*

```
curl thats-my.app -> cannot be resolved
```

*On the LAN Windows-PC Chrome Browser*

http://thats-my.app -> Website unreachable  /  DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

If you look at the "dig" - results it seams to me that Bind9 doesn't work right here. What do you think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution: The router ("AVM Fritz!Box", very common in Germany) has a security feature "DNS-Rebind-Protection" which prevents DNS requests from within the LAN to another host inside the LAN. As you set up an exception by typing e.g. the TLD "lan" or in the case above "app" in the textbox, your local DNS server works perfectly fine. You can remove the forwarders.

PS: You don't need the entry in /etc/hosts !

PPS: https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Good luck!